# ExpressJS skeleton root request cancelled

Tags: node.js, express, npm

Im trying to get started with expressjs. I created a skeleton by running `express expressSkApp`.

Once the skeleton creation is done and I start the server, I'm supposed to get response upon hitting http://host:port (http://localhost:3000). But nothing happens at all when I do this. From network monitoring I have found out the request is getting cancelled. And there is nothing in server log. Any reason for the request getting rejected?

After debugging a bit I saw in app.js there is a line of code `app.use('/', routes);` that redirects the request to a specific route. After debugging, I found out that the request is not getting redirected at all. The moment I change it to `app.use('/home', routes);` and hit the url http://localhost:3000/home, response is received.
Why is this behaviour? What if I want to hit http://localhost:3000/ and what it to be redirected to a concerned page? May be I'm missing out on something here.

My package.json dependency section looks like

```
 "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.9.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.8.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
    "morgan": "~1.3.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.1.3",
    "debug": "~2.0.0",
    "jade": "~1.6.0"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To Run a express framework  you need to run this  **DEBUG=expressSkApp ./bin/www** from the location of your project ( http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html ) . Another thing is Express uses route.js module which is very helpful, it makes url parsing very easy. For detail check this http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html